# Convert string to int to display delimted time using Split

Tags: c#

This is an attempt to convert a split string to an int format to display a user input time such as 2:15 meaning 2 hours and 15 minutes. I want to be able to multiply this time period by a dollar rate and add an additional cost. there is a subAmount and then a total both using ToString. Any 'clues' would be appreciated

```
    private void calulateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] item = timeTextBox.Text.Split(':');
        int hours, mins, rate, cost;
        int.TryParse(item[0], out hours);
        Convert.ToInt64(item[0]);
        int.TryParse(item[1], out hours);
        Convert.ToInt64(item[1]);
        int.TryParse(rateTextBox.Text, out rate); 
        int.TryParse(prescriptionTextBox.Text, out cost);
        int prescription = cost;
        int totalHours = hours;
        subAmountLabel.Text = totalHours.ToString("f2");
        int total = (totalHours) * rate + cost;
        totalAmountLabel.Text = total.ToString("f2");
    }
```

Comment: So what's wrong with it currently? What does it do vs not do? What errors are you getting?

Comment: any specific reason you dont want to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: "(local variable) int totalHours
(local variable) int rate

Error: operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type int and string"

updated the code as i made a typo <-- here '* rate'

by clues i mean to multiply time by rate: 1 hour 15 minute = 1:15 * $90.00 = $112.50
Is there a more accurate method etc!

Comment: please provide more details regarding your problem or, if your problem has been answered below, mark appropriate comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

You code sample seems perfectly valid (except you assign `hours` twice) but it contains some redundant lines. I fixed issue with `hours` and `mins`, got rid of unnecessary variables and instructions and edited `total` formula to include minutes as well:

```
        private void calulateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] item = timeTextBox.Text.Split(':');
        int hours, mins;

        int.TryParse(item[0], out hours);
        int.TryParse(item[1], out mins);

        double rate, prescription;
        double totalHours = hours + mins / 60.0;

        double.TryParse(rateTextBox.Text, out rate);
        double.TryParse(prescriptionTextBox.Text, out prescription);

        double total = totalHours * rate + prescription;

        subAmountLabel.Text = totalHours.ToString("G");
        totalAmountLabel.Text = total.ToString("C");
    }
```

Comment: int.TryParse(rateTextBox.Text, out rate);

Comment: int.TryParse(rateTextBox.Text, out rate); Sorry!it's underlined in red and reports '...has some invalid arguments.'

Comment: edited - it is because `int` and `double` are different types

Comment: Your answer gives the correct total (perfect) but its subAmount outputs a rounded up figure of the delimited time thus: 2:15 = 2 rather than the time * rate. cheers :) @Nogard

Comment: I do suspect you can accommodate output values according to their meanings in your flow much better then I :) my help was with fixing main formula and I hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark at what I think you are trying to do:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(timeTextBox.Text);

double rate, cost;

double.TryParse(rateTextBox.Text, out rate); 
double.TryParse(prescriptionTextBox.Text, out cost);

subAmountLabel.Text = ts.TotalHours.ToString("f2");
double total = ts.TotalHours * rate + cost;
totalAmountLabel.Text = total.ToString("f2");
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to do it as the sub and totals are way off track - cheers :)